# QE error: No handlers could be found for logger

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience, qasm

When I run a QASM program on a QE simulator, I get this error.

```
No handlers could be found for logger        
"IBMQuantumExperience.IBMQuantumExperience"
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Welcome! Perhaps you can provide a little more detail about your program and what you're attempting to do?